# Searching for a Whitman quote

Tags: quote-source, walt-whitman

I am looking for a quote attributed to Walt Whitman with the following approximate meaning:

> Finding faults with others requires a bit of ability,
>
> but stopping yourself from abusing that information requires a world of sense.

What is the exact quote (if there is one)?

Comment: I am working on a tool to list quotes based on words together with a friend. Unfortunately, the best I could find (with our tools and others) was this quote from Song of Myself: "What blurt is this about virtue and about vice? Evil propels me and reform of evil propels me, I stand indifferent, My gait is no fault-finder's or rejecter's gait, I moisten the roots of all that has grown." (If you want to try your luck different synonyms: https://quotations.ch/quotations -- would be interested in feedback)

Comment: @StefanHaustein  Wow, what a find!, I was just suggesting to a CS student that an AI/Natural Language Processor might help in this type of search! Looking forward to seeing more of your work.